# Nginx + Webmin - Request timed out

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, webmin, virtualmin

I have ubuntu server, installed Webmin and Nginx server to Run - NextJS, Express JS and Node JS Rest API.

Everything works well if I use IP address for API end point, but if I replace IP address with the domain name, it returns **504 Request Time Out**
Following is my Nginx conf file

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen XXX.XXX.XX.XXX;
    root /home/myuser/public_html;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;
    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_error_log;
    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/myuser/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/myuser/public_html;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
    
    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-nginx/16445681685115.sock/socket;
    }
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /api {
            proxy_pass http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:4000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       
    }

        location /admin {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /public {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
    
    location /upload {
        root /home/myuser/public_html/;
    }
    
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    listen XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/myuser/ssl.combined;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/myuser/ssl.key;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

If I run API via Public IP address -
**http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX/api/**
it works fine but if I run
**https://example.com/api/**
it returns **504 Request Timed Out**

Please help!!

Comment: `proxy_pass http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:4000` -- are you hardcoding the ip? how is it like when you start app using dns?

Comment: Yes, I am using public IP here "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX"

Comment: @LeiYang - It seems like there is some issue with SSL? it shows connection timed out with EXTERNAL_IP:443

Comment: i'm not sure. if i were you, i just configure all to localhost. never use ip unless really need to.

Comment: I thought it is a localhost which is causing 504 timed out so I changed it to PUBLIC IP